# Visual C++/CLI loading image added to resources to picturebox

Tags: image, winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

I am writing a WinForm application in Visual C++ and I attached some images to resources. Those images will all be used in one PictureBox and I want to switch between them via radiobutton selection. The thing that worked

```
void newton(void)
    {
        rheomod = 1;
        pictureBox1->Image = Image::FromFile("newton.png");
    }
```

but I think this loaded the pictures directly from the directory. I'm not 100% sure but I would like the app to use the images from resources.

I already added only the header
`#include "resource.h"` and don't know what to do next, because on MSDN there is no info how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found on another forum this solution which works really fine, you don't add the image to resource.resx but to MyForm.resx then the code:

```
        delete pictureBox1->Image;
        System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^  resources = (gcnew
            System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(MyForm::typeid));
        pictureBox1->Image = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^>(resources->GetObject(L"newton")));
```

Comment: This doesn't work as well as I thought, because MyForm.resx deletes my files... Anybody got a better solution? Please...